# Chrome OS (CR-48) mic boost?

Tags: audio, microphone, google-chrome-os, amplification

The built in mic is way too quiet. It seems to be line level and needs boosted. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have read that the best luck with this is to plug in a mic. You can get a combo mic and headphone with a trrs connection.

[image: TRRS]